# How to get the path of enterprise geodatabase stored in sql server?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, geoprocessing-service

I want to enter a geodatabase in a ListVersions tool.Output will be list of versions in a table.
Do i need to give a connection file path for Enterprise_GDB:*_*_
or path of actual GDB. and  how????
I am getting an error. Tool is not working successfully...

Answer (score 1):

If you are working from ArcGIS Desktop application such ArcMap or ArcCatalog, you should be able to list versions within a geodatabase by supplying either an .sde file connection path:

```
workspace = r"C:\GIS\conn.sde"
```

or path in notation

`Database Connections/connection.sde`.

If you are working from a stand-alone Python script, you have to use the .sde connection file or create it on the fly by using the GP tool Create ArcSDE Connection File. In either way, you will get an .sde file which will be the input for the [ListVersions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000000q000000) function of ArcPy. A sample:

```
import arcpy

database = r"C:\GIS\conn.sde"
versions = arcpy.ListVersions(database)

# Print the versions available to the user
for version in versions:
    print(version)
```